# Uma Class Library comum funciona em Silverlight?

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6, biblioteca, silverlight

Uma biblioteca de classes sem destino pode ser usada em *.NET Silverlight*?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A mesma, funcionaria em uma aplicação web de Silverlight? Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta é não.

O Silverlight utiliza um CLR diferente do CLR(Common Language Runtime) do .netframework comum. Por exemplo muitos recursos como acesso direto ao sistema de arquivos não é disponível.

No Visual Studio têm dois tipos de projetos possíveis que podem ser referenciados numa aplicação Silverlight:

- Silverlight Class Library
- Class Library(Portable)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse ultimo tipo de projeto pode ser referenciado tanto em aplicações Windows, Silverlight como Windows Phone.